# Convert jquery/js function to pass variable between pages to a ColdFusion variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, coldfusion

I have some jquery which checks if a particular element is visible on a page and passes a parameter to be appended to the url, so the element can be shown/hidden on the next page.

I want to see if it is possible to store this value in a coldfusion variable and then pass it via the navigation, as this seems to be a more robust method to me.

Here is my basic html:

```
<nav>
            <ul id="mainNav" class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="/">Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'work'>clicked</cfif>">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about"  class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'about'>clicked</cfif>">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/news" class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'news'>clicked</cfif>">News </a></li>
                <li><a href="/tumblr.com" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="subNav">
                <li><a href="/work/effort" class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'work' and VARIABLES.secondarydir EQ 'effort'>clicked</cfif>">Effort, We Cried!</a></li>
                <li><a href="/work/why" class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'work' and VARIABLES.secondarydir EQ 'why'>clicked</cfif>">Why Do We Do This</a></li>
                <li><a href="/work/guests" class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'work' and VARIABLES.secondarydir EQ 'guests'>clicked</cfif>">Guests &amp; Hosts</a></li>
                <li><a href="/work/prettygirls" class="<cfif VARIABLES.primarydir EQ 'work' and VARIABLES.secondarydir EQ 'prettygirls'>clicked</cfif>">Pretty Girls Doing Horrid Things</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

`#subNav` is set to hidden by default in the css.

I think have some basic jquery to toggle the visibility of the subNav:

```
    var toggleSubNav = (function(){
        trigger.on('click',function(){
            subNav.toggleClass('visible', function(){
                subNavLength = subNav.is(':visible');
            });
            return false;
        });
    }());
```

And then a second function which checks the visibility of the subNav and appends the url:

```
merge.on('click',function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            subNavLength = subNav.is(':visible');
            if(subNavLength){
                window.location = url + '?subnav=true';
            }else{
                window.location = url;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Finally a function which checks the url for the content of '?subnav=true' to display this on the next page:

```
var subNavProp = (function(){
        if(href.indexOf('?subnav=true') > 0){
            subNav.addClass('visible');
        }else{
            subNav.removeClass('visible');
        }
    }());
```

The variable `subNavLength` is global and gets updated via these various functions.

I realise I am posting an awful lot of jquery and I don't really know how (or if) there is a way to convert this to a backend solution for coldfusion. My thought was that I could toggle a class on the subNav element that is wrapped in a coldfusion if, something like:

```
<ul id="subNav" class="<cfif var IS true">className</cfif>">
```

But I am wondering if that still requires something of a Front End solution. Or even if there is another better way to do this?

Comment: <ul id="subNav" class="<cfif URL.subnav eq 'true' ">className</cfif>">        In second page you can change to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you have a few options, but it's not necessary to involve server-side in this. It's not even beneficial.

One, and probably the route I'd take, is to use a javascript cookie or localStorage to store the setting and that way maintaining clean urls.

Another route is using jQuery something like this.. I'm using a checkbox to toggle the addition, but it can be any variable, such as your `subNavLength`

I have this example designed to affect urls that begin with `/`, so that `#` urls and external urls are safe.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1ccgk6n/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click","a",function(e) {
        // This is just to demonstrate the change without trying to leave
        // JSFiddle, you can remove this whole function (a.click)
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on("change","#navChanger",function(e) {
        $("a").each(function () {
            if($(this).attr("href").charAt(0) == "/") {
                if(document.getElementById("navChanger").checked) {
                    if ($(this).attr("href").split("?").length > 1) {
                        $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href") + "&subnav=true");
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href") + "?subnav=true");
                    }
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href").replace(/.subnav=true$/i,"g"));
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Alternatively, here's how you can use localStorage to achieve a cleaner result, as it doesn't alter urls. Rerun the script to see the change after you click a set-button. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lj05rsm/))

```
var defaultOptions = {NavDisplay: true};
var options;
$(document).ready(function () {
    options = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("options"))||defaultOptions)
    alert("NavDisplay set to: " + options.NavDisplay)

    $(document).on("click", '#sFalse', function(e) {
        options.NavDisplay = false;
        localStorage.setItem("options", JSON.stringify(options))
    });

    $(document).on("click", '#sTrue', function(e) {
        options.NavDisplay = true;
        localStorage.setItem("options", JSON.stringify(options))
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. I think I am going to try and implement the cookie option. I would like to use localStorage although I have never looked at that in the past, so I will investigate.

Comment: I marked your answer also as I can see it is working in the fiddle, even though I am going to try and use a cookie method.

Comment: @lharby I updated my answer with a quick demonstration using localStorage (storage is so much easier to work with than cookies, only reason I chose that). Good luck.

Comment: thank you so much. I pretty much have local storage working (apart from one minor glitch) and that has allowed me to strip out alot of other extraneous code. I really appreciate your help.